# How do I prevent .htaccess rewrite from affecting folders?

Tags: .htaccess, directory, url-rewriting

Here is my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cp/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(?!\s*$).* $0.php [L]
```

This is affecting the folders in the same directory.
Here is an example folder directory:

- ..
- css/
- images/
- filename.php

If I the url: WEBSITE.com/filename is entered, the filename.php is pulled, but when I enter WEBSITE.com/css, WEBSITE.com/css/.php is pulled.

I do not want the .htaccess to affect sub-directories and do not want to put individual .htaccess files in each folder.

Comment: add RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jasssonpet.

I thought I was supposed to replace `add RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` instead of adding `add RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`.